# the variable in "for" returns null after gets the right value--setting a windows batch file variable to the day of the week in for

Tags: batch-file, variables, set, dayofweek

I have a windows batch file that runs daily. Wish to create a folder with the exact formatting name.
And I want to show weekday in the folder name, then something tricky comes out:

```
E:\tricks>for /F "skip=1" %a IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek') do set var=%a

E:\tricks>set var=5

 :\tricks>set var=

E:\tricks>set /p b=Name:
Name:
```

It seems like the variable "var" has already got the value"5" which means "Friday" but then the variable "var" become to "null" again. Could anyone help me with that? Many thanks!

here's the code:

```
for /f "skip=1" %%a IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek' ) do (set var=%%a)

set /p b=Name:
set mydt=(!)%DATE:~,10%("%var%")《" %b%"》
md %mydt:/=-%
```

Comment: Do not use links to pictures of text, just put the output as plain text into the post

Comment: There are many ways to deal with the "ugly" `wmic` output. In this specific case, just `... do set /a var=%%a` will do (the errormessage with the additional line can be redirected with `2>nul`).

Comment: Why are you using Win32_LocalTime to retrieve the DayOfWeek, then using a less robust and alternative method to retrieve the yyyy, MM, and dd values. Those values can already be retrieved from the same WMI command! Also are you sure that the characters `《`, and `》` are okay to use, for the codepage? and why are you including double-quotes in the value of `%mydt%`, those are not valid characters in a Windows directory name?

Comment: @jeb: Thanks, this is my first question on stackoverflow, will be careful on that in the future;

Comment: @Stephan: A very simple and useful method, thanks Stephan!

Comment: @ Compo: Hi Compo, thank you for your comment. I'm not a professional coder and just copy some other's code, I tried delete the double-quotes there and it also worked as before. As for《, and 》, they are in for the new created folder's name, it worked just the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

You observe the output of a for loop, when you see two assignements, then the FOR loops two times, because the output of the wmic command has a special line end.

You can fix it by breaking the loop after the first assignment.

```
for /f "skip=1" %%a IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek' ) do (
    set var=%%a
    goto :break
)
:break
```